# How to make a custom-width centered container in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, margin

I've been working with a very odd problem for the past day and I so far cannot understand where I am going wrong.

Firstly, what I am trying to do, is create a single column fixed container layout using Bootstrap, which is `33em` in width and is horizontally centered using auto margins.

The second thing I am trying to achieve, is using the `span` classes with this new `33em` layout.

How can I do this? I've somewhat achieved the first, however the auto margins are not working (they are different depending on the page).

Using LESS and Bootstrap 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your div centered create a one more class;

```
wrap {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 33em;
    height: 330px;
    margin-top: -165px;
    margin-left: -16.5em;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

And `<div class="container wrap"></div>` will be centered.